# JPA repository return one item from db but there are multiple item in the db

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I have the following function in my repository

```
Set<Felhasznalo> findAllByNevContainsIgnoreCase(String nev);
```

When I use this function in the controller I got back one User.

For example, if I have a String "John" and I call the repo function with that string I got back "John Doe" but I also have "John Doe Jr" in the db and I need him too.

Why I get only one User?

Comment: Use `Containing` instead of `Contains` (AFAIK) and make sure that you have a proper `hashCode` and `equals` method as you are using a `Set` those are important.

Comment: I doesn't change anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you are using a `Set`. Maybe you have implemented an `equals()` function which checks the names and the `Set` filters out duplicate elements.

Try changing your code to this:

```
List<Felhasznalo> findAllByNevContainsIgnoreCase(String nev);
```

So use a `List`.

Comment: I changed it to a List but I have the same problem

Comment: What happens if you do the query directly on your DB?
Try logging the queries done by Hibernate https://www.baeldung.com/sql-logging-spring-boot

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are storing your result in a `Set` which does not allow any duplicate values but here, you have duplicate names. Try changing `Set` to `List` as:

```
public List<Felhasznalo> findAllByNevContainsIgnoreCase(String nev);
```

Comment: I tried it but didn't help

Comment: Try writing `findAllByNev(String nev)` instead of `findAllByNevContainsIgnoreCase(String nev)`